# Decode double-back-slashes-prefixed octal codes in 'utf-8

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, character-encoding

I have a string `"\\303\\273"` that I want to decode into `û`.

It's known that `(decode-coding-string "\303\273" 'utf-8)` evals to `û`.

However, I'm not able to translate `"\\303\\273"` into `"\303\273"` with
`replace-regexp-in-string`.

**Question**: How to decode `"\\303\\273"` into `û`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"\303\273"` is 2 bytes and `"\\303\\273"` is 8 bytes, the problem with `replace-regexp-in-string` is it eagerly converts `\303` to `Ã` and `\273` to `»`.

```
(replace-regexp-in-string
 (rx "\\" (group (1+ (in "0-7"))))
 (lambda (s)
   (string
    (string-to-number
     (match-string 1 s)
     8)))
 "\\303\\273")
;; => "Ã»"
```

Here is a way without `replace-regexp-in-string`. Note that you need `unibyte-string` not `string`, since `string` will have the same problem as `replace-regexp-in-string`.

```
(decode-coding-string
 (apply
  #'unibyte-string ;; string does not work
  (mapcar
   (lambda (s)
     (string-to-number
      (substring s 1)
      8))
   (seq-partition "\\303\\273" 4)))
 'utf-8)
;; => "û"
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps.